# Can we say "You should have" by itself?

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say someone said, **"I didn't visit him yesterday."**. As a response to that, can I say **"You  should have."** to mean **"You should have visited him."**?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly say that. If I'm not mistaken, in grammar books, they call it **an ellipsis**. Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

This comment by @Michael Rybkin is correct.

> they call it an ellipsis. Look it up.

Try [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

BTW, your periods in the final sentence are wrong. They are ending a sentence that you want to continue. Most(*) would write:

> As a response to that, can I say "You should have" to mean "You
>   should have visited him"?

(*) Some style guides differ on whether quotes and dialogue are always punctuated the same.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, there is no rigid rule about that using or not using a period at the end of a quotation thing.

Comment: I would say there is a very rigid rule that a period followed by and end-quote mark ends a sentence. However, multiple sentences ended by periods  are allowed within one set of quote marks. Question marks and exclamation marks instead are optional: they may end the sentence but will not always do so.